# How to select and count pairs or triplets from 5 columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, combinations, combinatorics

I have a postgreSQL table where i store in five different columns (say col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) numbers. In each row the numbers stored are different from each other.

I want to make some select that gives me the pairs that exists and how many times they appear (count the times that they are present in rows).

Example:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 10 | 20 | 100 |
| 5 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 100 |

Results (something more or less like this):

| pair | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1,5 | 1 |
| 1,10 | 1 |
| 1,20 | 1 |
| 1,100 | 1 |
| 5,10 | 1 |
| 5,20 | 2 |
| 5,100 | 2 |
| 10,20 | 1 |
| 10,100 | 1 |
| 20,100 | 2 |
| 5,30 | 1 |
| 5,40 | 1 |
| 20,30 | 1 |
| 20,40 | 1 |

I can make some SQL to execute code in specific columns:

```
SELECT count (*) as total, col1, col2
FROM numbers
group by col1, col2;
```

But that won't give me all the combinations and I don't know how to get the rest of the pairs. Also, this may be inefficient in terms of performance.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Miguel.

Comment: I don't understand this question.. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `recursive` query for generating the output you are expecting

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d1f841ebc834fbee8da7ff85342eda0b)

```sql
-- You can change "select 3" to "select 2" or any number you want

with recursive col_join as (select 3),
               numbers_row as (
                   select *, row_number() over () as row
                   from numbers
               ),
               cte_r as (
                   select col1 as value, row, 1 as col
                   from numbers_row
                   union all
                   select col2 as value, row, 2 as col
                   from numbers_row
                   union all
                   select col3 as value, row, 3 as col
                   from numbers_row
                   union all
                   select col4 as value, row, 4 as col
                   from numbers_row
                   union all
                   select col5 as value, row, 5 as col
                   from numbers_row
               ),
               cte as (
                   select array_agg(value order by col) as value,
                          row,
                          col
                   from cte_r
                   group by row, col
                   union all
                   select c.value || cr1.value as value,
                          cr1.row,
                          cr1.col
                   from cte c,
                        cte_r cr1
                   where c.row = cr1.row
                     and not c.value @> array [cr1.value]
                     and c.col < cr1.col
                     and array_length(c.value || cr1.value, 1) <= (select * from col_join)
               )
select array_to_string(value, ','), count(*)
from cte
where array_length(value, 1) = (select * from col_join)
group by 1
order by 1
```

---

**Old scenario for joining two-column"

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8c7abf81abd0e7f7441a579d3a583c44)

```sql
with recursive 
  numbers_row as (
    select *, row_number() over () as row from numbers
  ),
  cte_r as (
    select col1 as value, row, 1 as col from numbers_row
    union all
    select col2 as value, row, 2 as col from numbers_row
    union all
    select col3 as value, row, 3 as col from numbers_row
    union all
    select col4 as value, row, 4 as col from numbers_row
    union all
    select col5 as value, row, 5 as col from numbers_row
  ),
  cte as (
    select 
      value as val1, 
      value as val2, 
      row, 
      col
    from cte_r
    union all
    select 
      c.val1 as val1,
      cr.value as val2,
      cr.row,
      cr.col
    from 
      cte c,
      cte_r cr 
    where c.row = cr.row and c.col = cr.col - 1
  )
select val1 || ',' || val2, count(*)
from cte
where val1 <> val2
group by val1, val2, val1 || ',' || val2
order by val1, val2
```

Comment: Thanks @Pooya... it works just how i asked. I didn't have much knowledge about SQL and PostgreSQL. I'm wondering what i need to change if i want to select triplets. Should i add one more column to cte select and it's union? Or do i need to add another recursive inside this recursive select?

Comment: You means, You want something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d8d880dca7309c5ee621e6c2dc714d73

Comment: Yes... many thanks... i tried to do something but i wasn't getting the desired results... it's a new knowledge that i have to study. However some results are wrong... the tiplet 5,20,100 should have total 2 instead of 1.

Comment: I'm trying to debug and understand your code for the triplets case... When selecting all records from cte i get this table that you can check on step 2 of this fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=00429ef1556f3d84d1eda84b36a8facc). 

In this table the triplet 5,20,100 appears only once and it should be there twice. Maybe the union is missing something?

Comment: I update my query and change the structure for support join two and three, etc columns. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d1f841ebc834fbee8da7ff85342eda0b

Comment: Thanks very much for your dedication to this question, it's awesome how it's done with a nice approach to have the parameter to build the response. Congrats!